# Auto scaling MongoDB as a service in Microsoft Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure

I see a MongoDB service in Microsoft Azure but that deploys a VM and installs MongoDB in that. I am guessing this will not auto scale and also charge me for the entire VM and MongoDB management (not just for my usage).

Is there any managed MongoDB as a service available in Microsoft Azure which will:

a) Auto scale.
b) Charge me only for my usage.

I see MongoDB container image by Bitnami but I might have to deploy this on Helm.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Atlas in a managed database as a service officially provided by MongoDB and it is readily available in all the three (aws, azure, gcp) major cloud providers.

[Automated MongoDB service on Azure](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/azure-mongodb)

Comment: Since the original question asked about auto scaling and usage costs: MongoDB Atlas can [automatically expand storage](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/faq/#faq-storage-limit) for dedicated clusters (M10+). [Auto Scaling of CPU & RAM](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/full-text-search-and-auto-scaling-coming-to-mongodb-atlas) is a new feature announced at MongoDB World in June, 2019 and is currently in private beta. You can also [pause an M10+ cluster](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/pause-terminate-cluster/#pause-a-cluster) for up to 7 days to reduce costs for a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any managed MongoDB as a service available in Microsoft Azure
>   which will:
>
> a) Auto scale. b) Charge me only for my usage.

**Yes**, As per MSDN BOL documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction) **`Azure Cosmos DB`** is Microsoft's globally distributed, `multi-model database service`. With a click of a button, Cosmos DB enables you to elastically and independently scale throughput and storage across any number of Azure regions worldwide. You can elastically scale throughput and storage, and take advantage of fast, single-digit-millisecond data access using your favorite API including SQL, `MongoDB`, Cassandra, Tables, or Gremlin. Cosmos DB provides comprehensive [service level agreements](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/cosmos-db/v1_3/) (SLAs) for throughput, latency, availability, and consistency guarantees, something no other database service offers.

For further your ref [Connect a MongoDB application to Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account)

Comment: [Cosmos DB pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) is based on provisioned throughput for Request Units (RUs) & consumed storage, so charging is generally on reserved capacity rather than usage. Cosmos currently doesn't provide auto-scaling as a built-in feature and will throttle requests when the provisioned RU limit is reached, however you could write Azure functions to dynamically adjust RUs. Cosmos has API emulation for MongoDB & other databases, but the implementation does not share any code with the emulated databases and differs in features and behaviour.